# Override getview not working

Tags: java, android

I'm a super noob. With that in mind, I'm trying to set the individual cells of a gridview to different colours. I know this question has been asked many times and I've read most of them.
I have seen many different ways of doing this but the simplest (I believe) was to @Override the getView method with:

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    int color = 0x00FFFFFF; // Transparent
    if (SOME_CONDITION) {
        color = 0xFF0000FF; // Opaque Blue
    }

    view.setBackgroundColor(color);

    return view;
}
```

The problem is that in the 3rd line, super.getview I get "can't resolve method". If I remove the "super" it does resolve but then says the Override does not actually override the superclass method, which makes sense but can someone please explain why the original code does not work.

Thanks

Comment: This code should go in the Adapter class, not in the GridView itself.

Comment: Ahhh... Makes sense now. Helps to understand the code right?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, there is no getView(...) method in GridView class for Android. You cannot override something which does not exist.

**Update:**
You will need to override the getView(...) method in your Adapter class.

Comment: Right, I thought it should go outside the class and was simply executed when the code got there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may be new in java, I think the following explanation of @Override will be helpful for you to diagnostic the problem on your own in the future:

> > Indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method declaration in a supertype. If a method is annotated with this
> >     annotation type compilers are required to generate an error message
> >     unless at least one of the following conditions hold:
>
> ```
> The method does override or implement a method declared in a supertype.
> The method has a signature that is override-equivalent to that of any public method declared in Object.
> ```

Your problem is #1.

Please refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html for more details.